# How to get filtered data from multiple checkboxes in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter, checkbox

I am fetching data from Api and based on api data I am filtering data when I click checkbox and the required data could be retrived i.e filtered data from one checkbox if I click and if I click another checkbox all of data disappears .I want to get all the filtered data which I clicked .Below is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const Filter = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        filterData()
    }, [])
    const filterData = async () => {
        const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        const data = await res.json()
        setPosts(data)
        console.log("posts", posts)
    }

    const handleClick = (e, userId) => {
        const { value, checked } = e.target
        console.log(userId, "userId")
        console.log(value, "val")
        if (checked) {
            const filterData = posts.filter((item) => item.userId === userId)

            setPosts(filterData)
        }
        else {
            filterData()
            //  const filterDat = posts.filter((e) => e === value)
            // setPosts(filterDat)
        }
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Filter data</h2>
            <label>Userid1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value='a' name='filter' onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, 1)} />
            <label>Userid2</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value='b' name='filter' onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 2)} />
            <label>Userid3</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value='c' name='filter' onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 3)} />
            <label>Userid4</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value='d' name='filter' onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 4)} />
            <label>Userid5</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value='e' name='filter' onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 5)} />
            <label>Userid6</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value='f' name='filter' onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 6)} />
            <label>Userid7</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value='g' name='filter' onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 7)} />
            <label>Userid8</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value='h' name='filter' onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 8)} />
            <label>Userid9</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value='i' name='filter' onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 9)} />
            <label>Userid10</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value='j' name='filter' onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 10)} />

            {posts.map((item) => (

                <div key={item.id}>
                    <div>{item.userId} ---- {item.title}</div>
                    <hr />
                    <div>{item.body}</div>
                </div>
            ))}
            <hr />

        </div>
    )
}

export default Filter
```

I want get filtered data based on all checkboxes

Comment: I think your `handleClick` is the problem. You're setting like this: `setPosts(filterData)`. Shouldn't it be `setPosts((prevFilteredData => [...prevFilteredData, filterData])`?

Comment: I have tried like this before but it is not working _setPosts((prev) => [...prev, filterData] )

Answer (score 0):

You are doing things other way around

1. Store somewhere state of the checkboxes e.g.:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(() => Array(10).fill(false));
// ...
const handleClick = (e, userId) => {
  const { value, checked } = e.target;
  setSelected((array) =>
    array.map((e, i) => (i === userId - 1 ? checked : e))
  );
};
```

2. Get filtered posts

```
const filteredPosts = posts.filter((item) => selected[item.userId - 1]);
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Filter = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(() => Array(10).fill(false));

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
      const data = await res.json();
      setPosts(data);
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (e, userId) => {
    const { value, checked } = e.target;
    setSelected((array) =>
      array.map((e, i) => (i === userId - 1 ? checked : e))
    );
  };

  const filteredPosts = posts.filter((item) => selected[item.userId - 1]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Filter data</h2>
      <label>Userid1</label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value="a"
        name="filter"
        onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, 1)}
      />
      <label>Userid2</label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value="b"
        name="filter"
        onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 2)}
      />
      <label>Userid3</label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value="c"
        name="filter"
        onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 3)}
      />
      <label>Userid4</label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value="d"
        name="filter"
        onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 4)}
      />
      <label>Userid5</label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value="e"
        name="filter"
        onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 5)}
      />
      <label>Userid6</label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value="f"
        name="filter"
        onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 6)}
      />
      <label>Userid7</label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value="g"
        name="filter"
        onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 7)}
      />
      <label>Userid8</label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value="h"
        name="filter"
        onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 8)}
      />
      <label>Userid9</label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value="i"
        name="filter"
        onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 9)}
      />
      <label>Userid10</label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        value="j"
        name="filter"
        onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, 10)}
      />

      {filteredPosts.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <div>
            {item.userId} ---- {item.title}
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div>{item.body}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Filter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a separate collection for the filered data and filter criterias.
Please refer the below code.

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-mestorf-6bunot?file=/src/App.js:0-1647

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const userIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedFilters, setSelectedFilers] = useState([]);

  const filterData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    const data = await res.json();
    setPosts(data);
    setFilteredData(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedFilters.length > 0) {
      const filterData = posts.filter((item) => {
        return selectedFilters.includes(item.userId);
      });
      setFilteredData(filterData);
    } else {
      filterData();
    }
  }, [selectedFilters]);

  const handleClick = (e, userId) => {
    const { checked } = e.target;
    if (checked) {
      setSelectedFilers((prev) => [...prev, userId]);
    } else {
      setSelectedFilers(selectedFilters.filter((x) => x !== userId));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Filter data</h2>
      {userIds.map((id, key) => {
        return (
          <>
            <label>{`UserId:${id}`} </label>
            <input
              key={key}
              type="checkbox"
              value="a"
              name="filter"
              onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, id)}
            />
          </>
        );
      })}

      {filteredData.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <div>
            {item.userId} ---- {item.title}
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div>{item.body}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```